# counting partitions of disjoint subsets into exactly 2 distinct subsets.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a_n$ denote the number of ways to partition $\{1, 2, 3, . . . , n\}$ into two disjoint subsets.

My question is **Find a recurrence relation for $a_n$ s.t $ n ≥ 2$**

EDIT: $a_n =2 a_{n-1} $

$a_0 = 1,  \space
a_1=2 $

that make sense?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking.  If order is relevant, then this is just the number of subsets (if $S$ is a subset then the partition is $(S,S^c)$).  If order is not relevant then you divide this by $2$.

Comment: Hmm im not sure what its asking eithier but im pretty sure order isnt relevant cause we are talking about disjoint sets, sets cant have order can they? they eithier have the element or don't?

Comment: No, I mean the ordering of the partition.  For example, if your big set is $\{1,2\}$ then we could look at the partition $((1),(2))$ or $((2),(1))$.   Same underlying two sets, different order.  Are these the same partition or not?  Like I say, it doesn't matter much...the two counts just differ by a factor of $2$.

Comment: ah i think understand what your saying, sadly the question is posted exactly as it is in my book so your guess is probally better than mine.  this is an introductory course to alot of stuff combinatorics is only a small part of it.

Comment: Like I say, it's easy to pass from one answer to the other.  Do you understand how to count the number of subsets?  If you insist on doing it recursively...suppose you have a partition of $\{1,\cdots, n-1\}$...can you see some natural ways to extend that to include $n$?

Comment: the number of possible subsets is just $2^n$  but counting exactly 2 subsets which are disjiont and have all of the elements in them is more difficult

Comment: No, it's still just $2^n$.  As I say, any subset $S$ gives rise to the partition $(S,S^c)$.  So the answer is either $2^n$ or $2^{n-1}$ depending on whether or not the order of the partition matters.

Comment: Oh, oh doesn't really matter which then but isnt that the the solution to the recurrence relation not the recurrence relation itself?

Comment: Yes, that's the solution.  To get the recursion note that, given a partition $(S_1,S_2)$ of $\{1,\cdots,n-1\}$ we can extend it to a partition of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ by adding the $n$ either to $S_1$ or to $S_2$.  Thus $a_n=2a_{n-1}$.  The only question is $a_1$ which is either $1$ or $2$ depending on whether $(\emptyset,(1))$ and $((1),\emptyset)$ are regarded as the same or different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a recursion start with a partition $(S_1,S_2)$ of $\{1,\cdots, n-1\}$ and note that we can extend it to a partition of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ by adding $n$ either to $S_1$ or to $S_2$.  In this was we see that $$a_n=2\,a_{n-1}$$

The only (slight) ambiguity lies in how we should compute $a_1$.  It is either $1$ or $2$ depending on whether or not we regard $(\emptyset, (1))$ and $((1),\emptyset)$ as distinct partitions.  That is to say, we have to decide whether the order of the elements in our partition matters or not.  That, of course, is a matter of definition.

Note:  to do the count, it's easier (I think) to avoid the recursion altogether and simply remark that for every subset $S\subset \{1,\cdots,n\}$ we get a partition as $(S,S^c)$.  Thus, if order matters, there are $2^n$ partitions and if order does not matter there are $2^{n-1}$.